# Having issue in my document.getElementby tagname

Tags: javascript

I have implemented document.getElementsByName('subject[]'); and document.getElementsByName('regional[]');
I don't know why it is not working .if I use any one it is working. what I have to do if both the subject and regional has to run properly.for sample understanding I have given this checkbox .Here checkbox is coming from mysql.But it gives source like this only. how to validate by using document.getElementsByName.

can any figure out what  is the problem in my code?what I have to do here.only subject and regional coming from mysql.I hope everyone understand the question

```
<form name="f1"action="" method="post">
    subject<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='science'>science<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='maths'>maths<br/>
    Medium<input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='Hindi'>Hindi<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='english'>english<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return check();"></form>

Here is my check:
<script>
function  check()
{
//alert('done')
var chk = document.getElementsByName('subject[]');
var reg = document.getElementsByName('regional[]');
var len = chk.length;
var regl=reg.length;
//alert(len);

if(len)
{
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
if(chk[i].checked){
return true;
}
else
{
alert('please select the subject');
return false;

}
}}
if(regl)
{
for(i=0;i<regl;i++)
{
if(regl[i].checked){
return true;
}
else
{
alert('please select the regional');
return false;
}
}
}
}
</script>
```

please check the condition what I have given here .may be this is also a problem to not working.if I write for subject[] alone it is working.If i combine regional[] it is not working.see my code.

Comment: where I have to change my code? help me by so

Comment: can any one guide me please?

Comment: if validation of `subject` is successful .`regional ` will not be validated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(regl[i].checked){
```

Should be

```
if(reg[i].checked){
```

Comment: Have you checked I have tried at my end?not coming. better jsfiddle. thanks for you help

Comment: Regl is the length, and cannot be indexed. I can't say that is the only error, but it is one. Bring up developer tools while using jsfiddle and see if it is throwing any errors

Comment: I have changed that  not coming.can spend some time for me. I could not trigger out even i changed that

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` does exactly what it says. It gets elements by their tag name. Since `subject[]` isn't an HTML tag name, of course this line wouldn't work, but don't fret! You can still get that element by doing the following:

`document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; //change index number for other inputs on the page`

Since the first `<input>` tag has the name `subject[]`, this is the element that will be returned along with all its attributes.

Comment: thanks lot here subject coming form db so it may 6 subject better we find the length and loop through it by checked property. how to get the length? you can see my form I have given subject[]. subject may be 5 or 8  and considered medium also. which property shall we need to use?

Comment: @ Brendan thats `document.getElementsByName()` not `document.getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: now please see this  second regional is not working it doesnot enter into if statement function  check()
{
var chk = document.f1.elements[('subject[]')];
var reg = document.f1.elements[('regional[]')];
var lenth = chk.length;
var r = reg.length;
alert("s"+lenth);
alert("r"+r);

if(chk)
{
for(i=0;i<lenth;i++)
{
if(chk[i].checked)
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert('please select the subject');
return false;
}
}
}

if(reg)
{
alert(reg);
}
}

Comment: can you try with jsfiddle since morning it has given worries for me. for this simple task